# How to fix automatic redirects?

Tags: redirect, urls, wp-redirect

All page links of my wordpress website are automatically redirecting  with additional string which looks like this `"/#.W6nTIaV-7pE"`

eg: https://supremeip.com/Trademark to https://supremeip.com/Trademark/#.W6nWKaV-7pE

How do I make it work? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't really redirects, the "Hash" part of a URL (the # and anything after that) are purely client side and will not trigger another request to your server.

The reason for it is AddThis. Here's an explanation as to why they are doing that:
[What is AddThis Click Tracking?](http://www.addthis.com/academy/de/addthis-click-tracking/)

You can disable it by adding an option to the addthis config:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var addthis_config = {
    data_track_clickback: false 
} 
</script>
```

Where and how to insert this depends on how AddThis is embedded in your site.